# Can't mount external HDD connected with SATA USB to a notebook

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, external-hdd, usb-drive

When I connect external HDD with SATA USB I get:

```
farmazon3000@farmazon3000HQ:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 80.0 GB, 80026361856 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9729 cylinders, total 156301488 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x5e83153d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63    40960079    20480008+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        40960141   156301311    57670585+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5        40960143    99553892    29296875    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       134711296   156301311    10795008   83  Linux
/dev/sda7        99555328   134705151    17574912   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order
farmazon3000@farmazon3000HQ:~$ ^C
farmazon3000@farmazon3000HQ:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1f75:0621 Innostor Technology Corporation 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 09da:c10a A4Tech Co., Ltd. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
farmazon3000@farmazon3000HQ:~$ ls /dev/sd*
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5  /dev/sda6  /dev/sda7  /dev/sdb
farmazon3000@farmazon3000HQ:~$ dmesg | tail
[ 3085.901270] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 7
[ 3089.708084] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[ 3089.843568] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0621
[ 3089.843579] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=5, SerialNumber=6
[ 3089.843585] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 20160414
[ 3089.844868] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3089.847121] scsi host7: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[ 3092.857370] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  ATA/ATAPI Device      PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 3092.858412] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 3092.867993] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
farmazon3000@farmazon3000HQ:~$
```

So my Ubuntu for sure sees some usb removable disc as `sdb` but I can't mount it:

```
farmazon3000@farmazon3000HQ:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/sataUsb/
mount: no medium found on /dev/sdb
```

There are some data on that disc that I want to use - I've put those data from my old PC which had also Ubuntu on it.

On Windows XP when I connect the external drive, OS shows "Removable device" (with pendrive icon) in My Computer but when I double click on it - it says "please insert the disc".

My notebook has only 2 USB 2.0 ports and I was trying both. The drive was not formatted. There is only 1 partition but I dont remember what kind. I don't have powered USB hub and I have no other computer to check. But this SATA USB thing is not an enclosure but simple plug with SATA on one side and two USB plugs on the other. One is for data the other is for power (of course one I plugged in notebook, the other is powered with 2A smartphone wall socket charger).

Comment: Are you plugging the external USB enclosure into a USB 2.0 port, or a USB 3.0 port? Does you notebook have both? Try the other port. Did you format the drive while it was in the Innostor case? Do you know what partitions are supposed to be on the disk? Does this enclosure work **anywhere**? Do you have access to a **powered** USB hub? Report back. Cheers, Al

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: If the drive was never formatted then use `gparted` to format it was `EXT4` (linux) or `NTFS` (windows).

Comment: These Innostor adapter have a reputation. The only way to know would be to try and format and partition the drive while it was connected via the Innostor. That will probably work. Understand that if you connect the drive elsewhere, without the Innostor, it will probably require another format. Just a characteristic of this adapter. Let me know. Cheers, Al

Comment: Wouldn't the data be wiped out when I format the drive?

Comment: Anyway gparted does not see that disk while connected via Innostor adapter.

Comment: Yes, formatting a drive will wipe it clean. I'm led to believe that the Innostor requires its own format on the drive. How are you powering the external SATA drive itself? I suspect a bad Innostor, or bad drive (but you have no where else to test it). Does the `Disks` application see the adapter/drive? Let me know. Cheers, Al